# Is JSON.Net guaranteed to always serialize the same way?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I need to generate a 'string' key based on the state of an object. I thought of serializing the object to JSON and use the result as key. This only works if JSON.Net always serializes the same way.

Is JSON.Net guaranteed to serialize the same way on the same machine if an object of the same class with the same state if encountered?

Comment: It looks the same on my tests... but that might be a coincidence. I like to be sure, that's why I'm asking the community. Hopefully somebody knows if the order is ensured by the JSON.Net framework.

Comment: @Jamiec Testing *guarantees* is impossible, not simple.

Comment: @Jamiec, especially when reflection is involved, guarantees are harder to test.  I once used a library (not Json.Net) that used reflection to map classes to flat files, and 99.9% of the time, it would work fine, but then it would randomly corrupt files because reflection makes no guarantee of the order in which e.g. PropertyInfo is returned, and though the library went through some pretty elaborate hacks to try to compensate for that (even using the Reflection api to modify private members of the Reflection api!), it didn't always succeed in compensating correctly. So definitely worth asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, otherwise the unit tests would fail.

There is an Order property on JsonPropertyAttribute if you want to explicitly state the order.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the reaction James!